# NullPointerException report from android market

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

A user submitted the following crash report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7202)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3778)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:886)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:886)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:886)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:886)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:886)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1716)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1124)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2125)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1700)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1822)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I can't reproduce it on any of my test phones (Xperia, HTC Desire, Galaxy S) (or the emulators), and the error report doesn't tell me where in the app the problem is or on what device (or who the user was so I can ask them for more information about what they were doing that caused it). I can't find anywhere in the code where I obviously try to use a TextView via findViewById without checking if it's null first.  None of the xml files have `android:onclick` in them, so it's not trying to call a mistyped function or something like that.  I tried comparing the lines given to the android source, but they don't seem to match directly, and reading the source of the named methods hasn't helped me.  (Disclaimer: I've only been using Java for a couple of months.)

Anyone have any idea what else I should check?

---

**ETA:** This is only place I have a touchlistener instead of a clicklistener is here:

```
btnDelete.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent meMotion)
  {
    int iAction = meMotion.getAction();

    switch (iAction)
    {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if (false == bKeyPressed)
        {
          bKeyPressed = true;
          deleteANumber();
        }
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDeleteTouch);
        mHandler.postAtTime(mDeleteTouch, SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
          + BUTTON_DELAY);
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        bKeyPressed = false;
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDeleteTouch);
        break;
    }

    return true;
  }
});
```

where mDeleteTouch is

```
private final Runnable mDeleteTouch = new Runnable()
{
  public void run()
  {
    // delete a number from the display
    deleteANumber();

    // then call self in BUTTON_DELAY ms, unless cancelled
    mHandler.postAtTime(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + BUTTON_DELAY);
  }
};
```

and deleteANumber() is

```
protected void deleteANumber()
{
  String strNumber = tvNumber.getText().toString();

  // only remove a character if there is at least one:
  if (strNumber.length() > 0)
  {
    strNumber = strNumber.substring(0, strNumber.length() - 1);
    tvNumber.setText(strNumber);
  }
}
```

which seems like it could be the problem as you can't call null.length(), but tvNumber is created with its text set to "", so getText().toString() should always return a non null value, right?

---

**ETA2** I've managed to get the same error on an HTC Desire HD, but it seems to crash without going back into my code -- setting breakpoints immediately inside the onClick doesn't catch anything.

---

**ETA3** If I comment out `tvNumber.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);` the problem goes away.

Comment: looks more like a event handler is null. are you passing a possible null anywhere to a textview?

Comment: Not obviously; I have just noticed that my datetime field in my SQLite db isn't set to not null like the rest, so I'll double check in case that's it, but I also set it to the current time on all inserts, so it should never actually *be* null.

Comment: The handler itself is not null (that is allowable), rather something you are doing in `onTouchEvent` is causing the NPE -- if you haven't overridden the `onTouchEvent` of the TextView then possibly there's a bug in the component. Have you asked the user what device this is on?

Comment: Unfortunately, google anonymise reports to android market, and the device type just says "other".  I can't talk to the user.  I do set an OnTouchListener for my delete button, but I return true, which should consume the touch, right?

Comment: @Joseph, actually, it says "platforms" is other, not device -- device isn't mentioned at all -- but either way, I don't know.

Comment: Aah I see. Yes it should, do you do anything else in your onTouchEvent ?

Comment: @Joseph, I've edited the code into the original.

Comment: @Ben Is the TextView editable? I would check if `strNumber` is null before using it just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Joseph, I haven't set the TextView to be editable, and I'm fairly certain it's not editable by default, but I'll check that.  I'll add the null check (though not being able to reproduce the problem, I'll never know if that actually fixed it, unless the crash gets reported to the market again. :( )

Comment: Yes I know, more a case of fingers crossed.

Comment: Yep -- "the basic class is configured to not allow editing".  Do you wanna stick the onTouchEvent comment in an answer?  I'll accept that.

Comment: I'm having same issue, and do not know where it is coming from.  Very frustrating.  I don't use setInputType() as explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the HTC Desire HD, touching a TextView with setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER) set appears to throw a NullPointerException.  Leaving that setting out prevents the crash, but necessitates manual input filtering (which isn't a problem in my case, but probably is in other people's).  Not a good solution, but a solution nethertheless.

Comment: Definitely true, thanks for pointing that out. We had the same problem, and were able to reproduce the bug thanks to your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I found that by specifying             android:inputType="phone" in the XML layout versus in code fixed out issue (was also crashing with TYPE_CLASS_PHONE).

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is not to use "setInputType" with a **TextView**. You don't need input type filtering for TextViews anyway since they are for displaying text only. **Input type is only needed for EditText** (and there it works). I had the same problem with Android versions below 4.2.

The disadvantage is, that applying input type "password" on a textview actually makes sense as it masks the password, which may be intended (it was in my case). But this causes the crash when touching the textview.