# Null Pointer Exception-android.widget.onTouchEvent

Tags: android

I got the following crash report in the android market place. While testing I haven't found any crash and my app works fine. Once I published my app I got the following crash report which I have shown below.

But I am not able to find where the crash occurs, I checked in some stack overflow question and there in some cases I got that use of `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);` make cause crash in some devices. Is it true because in my app in some activity I have used this line of code in order to change the input type of `EditText` from password-text / text-password?

Please help me to solve this out.

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7529)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3933)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
at  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1877)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1211)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2198)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1852)
at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2382)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2010)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_edit_passwrd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_passwrd_title"
    android:background="@drawable/img_password_textbox"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="195dp"
    android:hint="@string/passwrd_hint_text"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#121212" >
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check , `Have you mention Minimum_sdk_version in android-manifest?`

if not then following may be the reason of crashing your application--

If you are using that functionality of android o.s that does not support on customer device.Say you are using Finger_Pointer(as [MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html)) which does not support before android 2.0.

Or you are using `onBackPressed()` which does not support for android 1.6.I just gave you hint you can check other issue like this if you have

**Updated**

For HTC device, TextView's property `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER` lead to crash

[Here is the same problem discussed you can refer to this also.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978370/nullpointerexception-report-from-android-market)

Comment: yeh i mention android:minSdkVersion="8" , yeh i have used MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, in some of my classes. and i have used onBackPressed() also. but my minSdkVersion="8" which is 2.1 i think

Comment: That i don't know but my app support only for those devices having android 2.2 and up

Comment: @AndroidDev me to get same issue in Google play store. have you resolver that issue? if resolve that issue means help me how can i resolve that issue

Answer (score 1):

NullPointerException in my own experience tends to mean it cannot find a reference object for instance the edit text your setting the input type for cannot be found, check your layout references and how you've declared the EditText itself.

Comment: the problem lies on one of your TextViews, android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7529)
Its not being found/referenced correctly, (IN CODE) not in your XML

Comment: @How can i locate that crash...i test it but it never crash..so its very difficult to find the exact crash position

Comment: The easiest thing i can reccomend, is go to said line in your code (7529) find the textview and sourround it with a 'Try-catch' statement, that way the errors handled and the app wont simply crash

Comment: Open the file, CTRL+L type in 7529 press enter, check the code for all textviews at said location.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is not to use "setInputType" with a **TextView**. You don't need input type filtering for TextViews anyway since they are for displaying text only. **Input type is only needed for EditText** (and there it works). I had the same problem with Android versions below 4.2.

The disadvantage is, that applying input type "password" on a textview actually makes sense as it masks the password, which may be intended (it was in my case). But this causes random crashes when touching or scrolling over the textview.